# C++ - List is not keeping its elements

Tags: c++, list

I have 2 classes; TestUnit and TestShot.
TestUnit needs to hold a list of TestShots, however when I reference the list later on all the elements I've given it have disappeared!

**TestUnit.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "TestShot.h"

using namespace std;

class TestUnit
{
public:
    TestUnit(string);
    string getName(void);
    void addShot(TestShot);
    list<TestShot> getShots(void);

    bool operator == (const TestUnit& tu) const { return name == tu.name; }
    bool operator != (const TestUnit& tu) const { return !operator==(tu); }

private:
    string name;
    list<TestShot> shots;
};
```

**TestUnit.cpp**

```
#include "TestUnit.h"

TestUnit::TestUnit(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

string TestUnit::getName(void)
{
    return name;
}

void TestUnit::addShot(TestShot shot)
{
    shots.push_front(shot);
}

list<TestShot> TestUnit::getShots(void)
{
    return shots;
}
```

**TestShot.h**

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class TestShot
{
public:
    TestShot(string);
    string getName(void);

private:
    string name;
};
```

**TestShot.cpp**

```
#include "TestShot.h"

TestShot::TestShot(string name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

string TestShot::getName(void)
{
    return name;
}
```

**MAIN**

```
#include <string>

#include "exports.h"
#include "TestUnit.h"

using namespace std;

// Global Variables
list<TestUnit> testUnits;


int main()
{
    int nShots1 = 0;
    int nShots2 = 0;

    // Create Unit
    TestUnit *testUnit = new TestUnit("Name");
    testUnits.push_front(*testUnit);

    // Create Shot and add to Unit with same 'name'
    TestShot *testShot = new TestShot("Name");
    for (TestUnit unit : testUnits)
    {
        if (unit.getName() == (*testShot).getName())
        {
            unit.addShot(*testShot);
            nShots1 = unit.getShots().size();
        }
    }

    // Display number of Shots for each Unit
    for (TestUnit unit : testUnits)
    {
        nShots2 = unit.getShots().size();

        std::cout << nShots1 << ", " << nShots2 << std::endl;
    }


    system("PAUSE");
};
```

Output:

```
1, 0
```

So the list realises that it's been populated straight after adding to it, but it's then empty when I need to use it.
I'm guessing this is a scope problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.
All help is much appreciated!

Comment: `getShots()` is returning a copy of the list, not a reference to it.

Comment: Because C++ doesn't work like Java. Copying objects actually copies the object.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close this as caused by a simple typographic error because you didn't iterate by reference and hence only modified a copy of the element in the loop. I don't consider this a sufficiently advanced problem to make for a useful question.

Comment: you are also missing delete operands, no idea why you want to create objects with new and then pass the by value, guess you coming from java/C# learn how to work in c++ code.

Comment: Yeah, we don't use `new` anymore. Library code like `std::list` hides all that minutia.  In future, please post your code all in one great blob, not in fragments, or separate .h and .cpp files. No "Ikea code". :-) Read [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of your `for` loops, you're accessing the `list` elements by *value*, so you're effectively making a copy of what's in the `list`, modifying that, and then destroying it.  Change your loops to look like this:

```
for (TestUnit &unit : testUnits)
{
    if (unit.getName() == (*testShot).getName())
    {
        unit.addShot(*testShot);
        nShots1 = unit.getShots().size();
    }
}
```

Since you're using C++11 or later, you could also use `auto` instead of explicit typing (e.g., `auto &unit: testUnits`).

Comment: ... and don't use `new`.